# field don't update after have their first saves

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I'm an odoo developer and my problem is as follows: I want fields that already have registered values to no longer be modifiable afterwards.

I have some fields that I have created and I want after having received their first value when I come back for the next foix it refuses to I modify these fields.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to modify the fields because they are readonly fields. You need to remove readonly attribute from those fields in your models.py file.